# TinyMCE Focus Issue with Popups

Tags: tinymce, sapui5

I'm using TinyMCE text editor and I would like to upload an image by clicking on a toolbar button. But when the popup window was opened..:

- I can't select the input element.
- I can't type any image URL into the input field.

You can [access my code from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50148580/). Please take a look at the screenshot below.

[image: RichTextEditor Screenshot Image]

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue by using the following code. I hope it helps someone else who stuck with this kind of issue

```
openAddCommentDialog: function(oEvent,args) {
      var _this = this;
      if(sap.ui.getCore().byId("codeEditorContainer")){
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("codeEditorContainer").removeAllItems();
      }
      var commentEditor = new RTE({
        editorType: sap.ui.richtexteditor.EditorType.TinyMCE4,
        width:'100%',
        height:'100%',
        customToolbar: false,
        showGroupFont: true,
        showGroupLink: true,
        showGroupInsert: true,
        beforeEditorInit:function(oEvent){
          var config = oEvent.getParameter("configuration");
          config["setup"] = function(editor){
            editor.on('init', function(){
                if(args && args.commentMessage){
                  editor.setContent(args.commentMessage);
                  oModel.setProperty("/TicketItemModel/CommentTitle",args.commentTitle);
                }
                else{
                  if(args && args.commentTitle){
                    oModel.setProperty("/TicketItemModel/CommentTitle",args.commentTitle);
                    editor.setContent(args.commentMessage);
                  }
                  else{
                    oModel.setProperty("/TicketItemModel/CommentTitle","");
                    editor.setContent("");
                  }
                }
              })
          }
        }
      });
      if (!this._oDialogAddCommentWindow) {
        this._oDialogAddCommentWindow = sap.ui.xmlfragment("BnetPortal.Application.ToDo.fragments.addComment",this);
      }
      sap.ui.getCore().byId("codeEditorContainer").addItem(commentEditor);
      this._oDialogAddCommentWindow.open();
    },
```

Comment: Also you can change the editor config like this => config.menubar =false; config.language = "tr";